# Are there any advantages to using a getter inside the owning class?

Tags: java, encapsulation

I have discovered the following in some legacy code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private boolean myBool;

    public boolean getMyBool()
    {
        return myBool;
    }

    public void otherMethod()
    {
         // some other calculations
         boolean something = this.getMyBool();
         // some other calculations
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Is there an advantage to using `getMyBool()` and not just calling `myBool` directly?

Because as I see it, if the behaviour of `getMyBool()` changes, then this class will betray itself when calling this method.

Comment: Surely they're not declaring a local variable in a method, and not doing anything with it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other classes may inherit this one, and override `getMyBool()` with another implementation

- lazy initialization
- use a static attribute
- use some complex business logic
- ...

Another use case is when you want to instrument your code with aspects. Either for changing the getter behaviour, or for logging the getters invokations...

Comment: Is there a reason this would ever be preferable to using `protected` for the variable?

Comment: `protected` will let the variable be visible to all the subclasses. It doesn't change that subclasses may need to change the getter implementation, but let the superclass call this new implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not betrayal. If you use this class and use getter/setter outside class, changing of functionality is not betrayal either.

Imagine class Person. This class have age and you want to set value lesser than zero to zero. You just change setter and/or getter to appropriate behaviour.

You really do not want changing it from below zero to zero only "sometimes". This is reason, you should call setter/getter inside class.

Answer (score 0):

If `getMyBool` is a pure getter; that is, it only ever retrieves the field, then there's little value in making a method call to it.  There's no change in behavior between the getter and the field.

If it's *not* a pure getter, which does occur often, then the method call is acceptable.  Just using the getter wouldn't encapsulate the full intent of the program.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use `myBool;` in same class , you can use it directly. But you couldn't use this value in other class because it's access specifier is `Private`. Private members we cannot use and inherit it into other class.   But you can call and get the same value from `getMyBool();`method. It is public method. we can use it from any where.

Comment: A class can use its private fields.

Comment: Agreed. I mentioned same in my post.  If we want to use private value from other class. We couldn't.

Comment: Yes, but I'm really not sure what you're mentioning it here for.  There is no other class to consider here, so whether or not the field is private is immaterial.